# Javascript error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to draw a chart using the Google Visualization API, by deferring the load of the api only to when I'm using the visualizations is being needed.

The Deferring is working properly and the callback is also working properly, but I'm not being able to get the Data parameters into it the following error appears.

[image]

```
    addGoogleChartScript: function () {
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "http://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=superlist.loadGoogleChart";
      script.type = "text/javascript";

      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    },

   loadGoogleChart: function () {
    google.load("visualization", "1", {"callback" : superlist.waitForGVisAndLoad, 'packages':['corechart']});
   },

   waitForGVisAndLoad: function (fn, params) {
    try {
        var data = params[0];
        var text = 'Waiting for Google API to display chart...';
        var h1 = $s('#suplist_item_' + data.id + ' h1');
        if (google && google.visualization && typeof google.visualization.arrayToDataTable == 'function') {
            if (h1.innerHTML == text) h1.innerHTML = h1.getAttribute('prev');
            fn.apply(null, params);
        }
        else {
            if (h1.innerHTML != text) {
                h1.setAttribute('prev', h1.innerHTML.toString());
                h1.innerHTML = text;
            }
            setTimeout(superlist.waitForGVisAndLoad.bind(null, fn, params), 500);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
  },
```

Comment: Are you including the script before the head element exists?

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm adding the script at the moment the user save the data to create the chart.

Comment: How do you provide the `fn` and `params` in your function call in the `waitForGVisAndLoad`? What I would assume is that you're unable to read [0] of ´params` as it's not defined.